# Android: Is there a universal way to send the MMS on any android devices?

Tags: android, android-intent, mms, htcsense

This code works on the plain google devices with native android system. But there is no MMS app in the list on htc sense devices and I don't know about Motorola Blur etc.:

```
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("image/png");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, context.getString(R.string.send_intent_name)));
```

This code works on the htc sense but not from the Chooser, what I really need:

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND_MSG");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    sendIntent.setType("image/png");
    context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

But I don't know how to combine this code samples together and I don't know how to determine Htc Sense ui programmatically. Is it right way to support different type of devices?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: Have you seen [this question][1]? It has some sample code.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016

Answer (score 1):

Sense, especially the older versions are a pain.  There webview control also has a bunch of problems.  Depending on volume of messages you might try using a webservice like amazon's simple notification service to send sms messages: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/11/amazon-simple-notification-service-now-supports-sms.html
Its not an android solution, but it might work.

Answer (score 1):

You could detect whether there's a responder for the HTC Intent, and then branch:

```
intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND_MSG");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.setType("image/png");

resolves = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

if (resolves.size() > 0) {
    // This branch is followed only for HTC 
    context.startActivity(intent);
} else {
    // Else launch the non-HTC sense Intent
    intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/png");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
            context.getString(R.string.send_intent_name)));    
}
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You may use it like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{""});
i.setType("video/3gp");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + attachmentFilePath));
startActivity(i);
```