# Sending MMS using httpConnection (Android 2.1)

Tags: android, mms

i am trying to send MMS using code sample from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016). I am not sure I understand how to deal with `MMSPart part` and `parts` vars: where and how should they be filled?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MMSPart is internal class for keeping data. Checkout this example:

Declaration:

```
class MMSPart {
public String Name = "";
public String MimeType = "";
public byte[] Data;
}
```

Example:

```
...
final MMSPart samplePart = new MMSPart();
samplePart.Name = "sample";
samplePart.MimeType = "text/html"
samplePart.Data = "<b>Hello !</b>".getBytes();
...
```