# Sending MMS using httpConnection - Add Image to PDU

Tags: android, mms

i was able to send an MMS using DK's code sample from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050749/sending-mms-using-httpconnection-android-2-1). I'd like to put an image into the MMSPart class. I think the mimetype will be "image/jpeg" (correct me if I'm totally worng on that), but how to I put an image into the Data parameter - do I need to read the image into a fileInputStream or bitmapfactory and set the .Data value to it?

**UPDATE** - tried asahi's code and I think I'm getting closer, but now I'm getting an out of memory error. Here is the info from logcat..

--first this--

```
Out of memory on a 3602732-byte allocation.
```

--then this--

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:85)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:69)
at java.util.Arrays.toString(Arrays.java:2659)
at com.market.mmsapp.HttpUtils.httpConnection(HttpUtils.java:88)
at com.market.mmsapp.slimMmsActivity.UploadFile(slimMmsActivity.java:132)
at com.market.mmsapp.slimMmsActivity.onCreate(slimMmsActivity.java:46)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Bitmap b =  Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), bitmapUri);

b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, os);

mmsPart.Name = fileName;
mmsPart.MimeType = "image/jpeg";
mmsPart.Data = os.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a try, but now I'm getting a java.lang.OutOfMemory error. The image I am loading is 70K. I wonder if there is some limitation on the file size for the MMS. I am going to keep trying things. Has this ever worked for you?

Comment: yes, the code above is from a working application. Can you post log?

Comment: Thanks - I added the log to my question above.

Comment: I got it. It was the image size. I resized it down and it worked.

Comment: I know this was answered some time ago but did you notice if the images would arrive with a normal size?

Comment: as it was answered some time ago... I'd say I did not notice anything abnormal back then.

Comment: do you know if there's a limit to the size image I can send in a mms?

Comment: sometimes operators impose limit on size of attachments. other than that - do not know