# Sending MMS in Android

Tags: java, android, mms

I'm trying to send MMS using code sample from [How to send image via MMS in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016), but the last step `HttpUtils.httpConnection` throws an exception:

> `java.lang.RuntimeException`: This thread forbids HTTP requests

What's the problem? Please help me.