# Sending SMS and MMS

Tags: android

I'm looking at replacing the default Android text messing app with my own, but I don't exactly know how to send SMS and MMS text messages.  I would like to at least get it so that I can send SMS first, since I would assume that sending MMS would be much more difficult.

So, what exactly should be done when sending messages of these types? Any code examples that would be easy enough to understand?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016

Answer (score 2):

Check the a[ndroid-smspopup](http://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/) source code.

Answer (score 0):

> So, what exactly should be done when sending messages of these types? Any code examples that
>   would be easy enough to understand?

Use `SmsManager`. Here is [a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SMS/Sender/) showing the basics of sending an SMS, either through the default client or by using `SmsManager`. I do not believe there is a public API to send MMS, though.

Comment: Even though there is no public API to send MMS, there are third party texting apps which do so.  How are they able to send MMS?