# Send an image (stored in drawable) via MMS

Tags: android

A number of images are "built in" to my app. They are stored in the drawable folder. I'd like to give the option of sending one of these images via mms (or even email) to someone in the user's address book. All the examples I've seen are sending images that are stored somewhere other then the default Eclipse drawable folders.

I've looked over the answers regarding MMS. It looks like this should be simple, but I don't understand how to do it. Is it that I first must copy an image from the default location to where other apps can see it? Any sample code would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SMS is limited to 140 characters.  But 1x1 gif file is 8 bytes, you're not going to get much in 140, and you might wind up having to split the information across hundreds of SMS messages...  And order is not guaranteed....  If you really want to, you can simply take the [base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) of any file you like and transmit it via SMS.  You'll probably need to tag the SMS with a number and also another tag to denote the end of a file.

Then, of course, you'll also need some sort of app on the other end to reconstruct the image from the base64 chunks...

Unless you were talking about MMS.  That's a different beast altogether...

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant mms. Actually, the question is applicable to email as well. When I have an image stored in my app, how to I let other services see it?

Comment: Check this out then. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android

Comment: Hey @OmnipotentEntity, have you gotten that example to work?  I am having some issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-sms-mms-in-android