# not showing "Messaging" option when try to send MMS programatically

Tags: android

We are using below code to send MMS but in some devices showing "Messaging" option but in some devices not showing "Messaging" option. And its showing rest of options like bluetooth, dropbox, email, evernote, etc. please correct me if i am doing something wrong.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/tmp.jpg"));
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
sendIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Image To:"));
```

Comment: i think u cant do a lot in this case, bcoz as soon as u call startActivity() control goes to android itself means it broadcast intent of the type Intent.ACTION_SEND. now the activities which have set the intent filters for this kind of intent appears in the list. still try replacing jpg or png in place of *.

Answer (score 0):

Not all android phones are required to have the "Messaging" app.

Comment: I want to send MMS through my application, i found that there is a way to send MMS through opening default messaging application. if some of android device do not seem to have Messaging app then what is the best way to send MMS through my application. Can you please suggest me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016

Comment: Hey @Falmarri, i looked into the example you gave of sending MMS, but I am having some issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-sms-mms-in-android . How did you get this to work?

Comment: @toobsco42: Ask a new question. This answer is 2 years old.

Comment: Hey @Falmarri, I have asked a new question HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-sms-mms-in-android