# how to send an MMS programmatically?

Tags: android, mms

I'm trying to write an app that send an MMS without user interaction (i.e. not using the ACTION_SEND intent), following what suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android).

The statement

```
     HttpUtils.httpConnection(context, 4444L, MMSCenterUrl,
        bytesToSendFromPDU, HttpUtils.HTTP_POST_METHOD, !TextUtils
                .isEmpty(MMSProxy), MMSProxy, port);
```

return me an error that say that the statement cannot run in the same thread.
So, I build a separate thread using the AsyncTask class and the doInBackground method.

Now, I'm receiving the following error

> 02-14 17:49:27.519:
>   WARN/System.err(1884):
>   java.io.IOException: Connect to /213.230.130.89:80 timed out 02-14
>   17:49:27.649: WARN/System.err(1884):
>   Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException:
>   Connect to /213.230.130.89:80 timed
>   out

where 213.230.130.89 is my MMSProxy (the MMSCenterUrl is "http://mms.tim.it/servlets/mms").

pls consider that I'm able to send an MMS from the user interface with the same settings.

does anyone have any idea on what I'm missing?

thanks in advance.

[edit]
I found the mistake.
according to [D. Kołakowski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android): "If you get result with Phone.APN_REQUEST_STARTED value, you have to wait for proper state. Register BroadCastReciver and wait until Phone.APN_ALREADY_ACTIVE appears".
So I did a receiver for checking the phone connectivity status and, only then, perform the http-post request. 
Now it's working.

Comment: If you found the mistake, then please add an answer and accept it, so this question doesn't linger around in the "unanswered" section.

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)

Comment: The following link can help you. http://androidbridge.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-send-mms-programmatically-in.html

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748209/receive-mms-messages-in-android-kitkat