# How to send MMS using my code

Tags: android, mms

I've searched for couple days about sending MMS，all i can find is the intent.ACTION_SEND things.I'm building a messaging program and i really need this mms sending feature. Any tips about it? Is there any API for sending MMS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android

Answer (score 2):

If you have to **send mms with any image** then this code.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/image_4.png"));
            sendIntent.setType("image/png");
             startActivity(sendIntent);;
```

**OR**

If you have to **send mms with audio or video** file then used this.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
                sendIntent.putExtra("address", "1213123123");
                sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "if you are sending text");   
                final File file1 = new File(mFileName);
                if(file1.exists()){
                    System.out.println("file is exist");
                }
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file1);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                sendIntent.setType("video/*");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
```

any query please replay.

Answer (score 0):

Why does not ACTION_SEND suit you? What exact functionality do you need?

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, 
Uri.parse("mms://")); 
sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg"); 
String url = "file://sdcard//tmpPhoto.jpg"; 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url)); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "MMS:"));
```

Crude example, but even though as you see you may input any type of data there using MMS. You may also check this link, if you want more info: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms

Comment: Intent.ACTION_SEND is ok, but I'm planning to send MMS using my own program, it's a little weird to jump to another program and send a MMS, rather than using my message sending program

Comment: Ok then check the link that i gave you and the sources. There is an API how to work with it. First check if MMS isConfigured/enabled, then send it. The code is in src folder