# Sending MMS Through Android Code

Tags: android, mms, apn

I'm looking at [the code posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016) for sending MMS through an Android Application, and I'm very close.  I have successfully sent an MMS while the Wifi connection is NOT enabled.  But when it comes time to use the `httpConnection` in never connections when Wifi is enabled.  I've read several posts saying to use

```
ConnectivityManager.requestRouteToHost(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_MMS,APNBACKENDIP);
```

And that function returns `true` meaning that it should route traffic over the `TYPE_MOBILE_MMS` interface, but it always times out.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Also I tried using `TYPE_MOBILE` instead of `TYPE_MOBILE_MMS` and the function returns false instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an incredibly simple answer....I had my IP quad reversed when calculating the IP address for requestRouteToHost.

I.E I had:

```
int address = ((addr[0] & 0xFF) << 24) | ((addr[1] & 0xFF) << 16) | ((addr[2] & 0xFF) << 8) | (addr[3] & 0xFF);
```

Whereas it should be:

```
int address = ((addr[3] & 0xFF) << 24) | ((addr[2] & 0xFF) << 16) | ((addr[1] & 0xFF) << 8) | (addr[0] & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Could you provide your code for sending MMS. It will be appreciated if you do that. I tried to search all over the internet and read the docs and came out with nothing :(

Comment: Hey @apmeyers1987, i looked into the examples you gave of sending MMS, but I am having some issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-sms-mms-in-android . How did you get this to work?