# Where is com.google.android.mms.*?

Tags: java, android, mms

I am writting an application that will send MMS messages from an android phone and I am trying to follow the instructions on this post:

[How to send image via MMS in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016)

My problem now is I can't find the libraries used there, like com.google.android.mms.*

Can anyone point me to that?

Is there any MMS library I can plug in my project? It is kinda weird that google does not provide that for the developers...

Thanks,

Joao Paulo Farias

Answer (score 1):

you can get it this way

```
Class pduparserclass = Class.forName("com.google.android.mms.<the class>");
```

since the class is present on the device but not in the sdk. this will not work on the emulator

Answer (score 1):

One way is to download the jar, and have it added to your build path.
You can download at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidsrcjar.htm

Comment: This package is exactly what I need, only problem is once I add it as a resource eclipse does not detect the class files inside each package, only the package names.

Answer (score 0):

com.google.android.mms is an internal package in Android's source code. It is not intended to be used by other apps.

The link you posted already contains code on how to send an MMS using the proper API in aioobe's answer (who in turn linked to another answer that had it).