# Sending a picture message in android?

Tags: android, mms

Can i create an application which can send the picture message without using intent??
Also in my application i know the destination number and the location of the image, so can i perform this action on a button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

[How to send image via MMS in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Using HTTP-POST is there any other classes needed for the code to be run?? Some compilation issues areb there..

Comment: What's wrong with Intents? As you can see from the second answer, it's much easier to send a message using an Intent.

Comment: Using intent its impossible to hide UI.. Actually i need to perform the sending mms in a simple button click????