# Android sending image via mms programatically(Operation timed out)

Tags: android, messaging, mms

I want to send an image via MMS programmatically in Android.  I am following the links below:

http://androidbridge.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-send-mms-programmatically-in.html

[How to send image via MMS in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android)

It works sometimes but mostly I get a "java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out".

Can any one provide more information regarding this problem?

Comment: what errors you are getting ?

Comment: Its working for some cases but many cases iam getting   java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out

Comment: then increase your Timeout by using setConnectTimeout();

Comment: Please mention in your question the issue which is SocketException "Operation timed out".

Comment: Even i increase it to 20 sec . after 20 sec iam getting same error..

Comment: hello Yaqub Ahmad i didnt get you..

Comment: Check the LogCat what does it say? & then provide the exception detail so someone can help you.

Comment: may be due to settings i think.. when i try to catch the exception iam getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mms1.live.vodafone.in/mms/ i am using vodafone  network.I recieved mms settings and also installed them.??I am able to send mms without any problem from my native application.But unable to send from my application??

Comment: This is the example which i am using http://www.ziddu.com/download/14286605/SendMMS3.zip.html

Comment: how to send message body, i found only subject can be send..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are really having a timeout.  You say it sometimes works... Do you have a reception problem with your 3G (or whatever you are using) data network in your area?

If you are surfing the internet from the same location and pages don't load refresh and timeout, then that's probably your problem.

Try where you know the reception is good.  You can bypass this problem by catching the exception and retry the sending of the message a few more times before popping a message to the user that the message could not be sent or the such.  Better yet would be to save a history of unsent messages so that the user can resend them later.  Of course I am assuming that the sending of the message is user driven.  If not, you could check the data reception from time to time (every few minutes) and then resend when good enough until it goes through.

Hope that I helped.

Answer (score 0):

MMS is just a htttp-post request send using extra network

```
you can download the source code here.
http://www.ziddu.com/download/14286605/SendMMS3.zip.html

I checked.Its work.
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Comment: @patel I get connection time out at "out = connection.getOutputStream()" in mmsender.java

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble with sending MMS. I would really appreciate it if you could help me! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448316/cannot-send-mms