# How to add androidprovider.telephony.mms to my package

Tags: android, mms

I have downloaded source code for mms application from [android.git.kernal.org](https://github.com/android) site.But It showing errors for some of the packages missing like androidprovider.telephony.mms.
How to add androidprovider.telephony.mms to my application..?or can any one suggest a better approach for sending mms without using native intents and httppost method
    ([How to send image via MMS in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016)).

Answer (score 0):

> How to add androidprovider.telephony.mms to my application

You don't. The MMS application can only be built as part of a full firmware build.