# How can I send an MMS from my Android application using an Intent?

Tags: java, android, message, mms

I want to send MMS from my app and i doing a lot of search and have nothing just 2 codes :
the First one is this:

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 sendIntent.setType("image/jpg");
 sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
 sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "hello");
 sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
 startActivityForResult(sendIntent, 0);
```

So, My Question is,

1. is this works?
2. is it complete code ? if not what should i add ?

Comment: why not try it out and see?  Worst case it doesn't work and you get some valuable input via exceptions/errors (or even worse you don't get exceptions but it doesn't work).  Best case...it works.

Comment: You should really read into this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android). It has many example codes and explanations.