# Where is /res/xml/mms_config.xml located?

Tags: android, xml, mms

I'm attempting to send MMS implementing the method outlined here: 
[How to send image via MMS in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android)

To do so, I imported com.android.mms to my Eclipse project (among other imports); however I cannot overcome one issue. In class MmsConfig:

```
private static void loadMmsSettings(Context context) {
    XmlResourceParser parser = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.mms_config);
```

R.xml.mms_config is unresolved. From where do I locate/obtain this resource? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you are `import`ing your own `R` instead of `android.R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I imported com.android.mms to my Eclipse project (among other imports)

Note that firmware apps are not designed to be built independently of the firmware.

> From where do I locate/obtain this resource?

From the same place you got the source code. In Android, this is a XML resource, found in the project's `res/xml/` directory. Hence, if you go to the project where you took the code, and you look in `res/xml/`, you will find [the `mms_config.xml file](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/res/xml/mms_config.xml).