# How to send an downloaded image via MMS in Android

Tags: android, email, mms

In my application I am downloading an image from server.Now I want to send this image via MMS & Email.

How can I do that.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First save the image in the SD Card and then use the following code to open the MMS application for sending the saved image:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));//put the uri of your image here
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
```

read [this link](http://jtribe.blogspot.in/2008/12/sending-mms-with-android.html) for more info.

Read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android) for sending MMS programmatically.

Comment: Hi Praful I am facing an issue.Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615136/issue-on-sending-mms-in-android-version-4-0-3