# android Send text Message with Image

Tags: android

How to send Text Message With Images **without user intervention**

```
short SMS_PORT = 15005; 
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
smsManager.sendDataMessage("5556",null,SMS_PORT,bFile,null,null);
//bFile is a Image byte Array which is stored in sdcard
```

Text Message Send successfully but Image doesn't send

Comment: For sending Image you have to use MMS service not SMS..!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android

Answer (score -1):

Use this code and let me know if it worked:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
```