# How does Android Send MMS

Tags: android, mms

Is there a simple code to download that provide the sending of an MMS using Android.
I found many example but not the full code. Please Help me.

Comment: then you should at least try to make it "full"

Comment: What did you find and why could you not implement it?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a begginer in Android. That's why i look for a "full" in order to understand more.

Comment: I found this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016)

Comment: Google it. hope you found the ans in first 5 links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly found the below link to download source code

http://www.ziddu.com/download/14286605/SendMMS3.zip.html

And you will get instruction from the below link

http://androidbridge.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-send-mms-programmatically-in.html

And you can see the below link for example of how to send MMS

http://matrix-examplecode.blogspot.in/2011/08/send-mms-example.html