# Sending images over SMS in phonegap, possible?

Tags: javascript, cordova, sms, share, phonegap-plugins

I'm working on "Greeting card" app, in which the app allows the user to send the greeting image through sms and email in phonegap, but after searching alot i found that, images cant be sent through SMS by this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/9hX2DiUDRv4). right now dont know what to do, is there any way to send the image over SMS? please help me.

Comment: you have to use MMS. currently there's this plugin but it is unstable: https://github.com/christyrajupaul/Phonegap-MMS-Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer: NO you can't send images through sms in any kind of Mobile OS.

You should use MMS (Multimedia Messaging Service) in certain conditions, and you should write your own plugin for phonegap.

to know how to do it, check this answer "[How does Android Send MMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497472/how-does-android-send-mms)"