# How to send MMS without intent programmatically

Tags: android, mms, smsmanager

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test.png");
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.putExtra("address","1234567890");
    i.putExtra("sms_body","This is the text mms");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,"file:/"+uri);
    i.setType("image/png");
    startActivity(i);
```

I want to send MMS but I don't want to use intent object like above because I am developing my own application of sms manager. So how can I send MMS?

I am referring [to this link code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016) but I don't understand it and it doesn't work.

Comment: This is the code to send sms and this was i already created I want to add photo in my screen and then it will send to specific person.

Comment: could this post be of any help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2973016/878126 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no public API to send an MMS in Android at the moment.

Comment: @user2436235 If you have a server to receive it and then forward it on to your application on the recipient user's device, then yes.

Comment: @user2436235 It'd be simple client server communication. There's hundreds of tutorials out there

Comment: hey Raghav can u give me any example how to do it??

Answer (score 1):

**MMS is a HTTP based request in Android.**
You have to have mobile data to send an MMS.
There are no APIs exposed by Android to send an MMS, as they have APIs for SMS.
If you want your application to send MMS you will have to write everything.
Please refer the AOSP code. https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms 
OR you can simply build the Intent and then launch the native Messaging App.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble with sending MMS. I would really appreciate it if you could help me! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448316/cannot-send-mms

Answer (score 0):

Android's SmsManager API now supports this functionality since API level 21, with the [`sendMultimediaMessage`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendMultimediaMessage(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) method:

> ```
> void sendMultimediaMessage (Context context, 
>                 Uri contentUri, 
>                 String locationUrl, 
>                 Bundle configOverrides, 
>                 PendingIntent sentIntent)
> ```