# how to send image to a contact number in android

Tags: android, mms, smsmanager

I am able to send normal message to a number through `SmsManager`. But I want to send `image(mms)` along with text message. I know it can be sent through Intent with `ACTION_SEND`, but I am using `SmsManager`. But searching about it, some sources say it might not be possible. But has someone made it possible?

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

Comment: I think you can send only with intent ACTION_SEND

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016. check this not so straight forward as sending text messages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016. here's a blog on the same.