# Send MMS automatically (without user interaction)

Tags: android, send, mms

Please Guys ! I want to send MMS automatically without user interface as for SMS using this code :

```
 String messageToSend = "this is a message";
 String number = "2121234567";

 SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, messageToSend, null,null);
```

This code works well for SMS but how can i do it for MMS please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to send the MMS without user interaction in android. You can find the code on the stackoverflow [How to send image via MMS in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android?lq=1)

But this still not the good way because it need the APN settings to send the MMS. For Android 4.0+ you can't get the APN Secure Settings in android. So I recommend to you to send the MMS using the Intent.

To send the MMS using Intent :-

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/image.png"));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: how do you specify the recipient in this case?