# android capture photo and save it in image view and send it MMS?

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview, android-camera

I want to take photo and display it in image view with delete button in image view if i dont want the photo and take another photo and send the photo taking via MMS.

Comment: You could check the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5991319/2688283). You should also refer to [android's documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html).

Answer (score 0):

Declaring Button and ImageView

```
ImageView imageView= (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Button OnCLick to Capture an Image

```
 photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
            }
        });
```

Place the Captured Image Into ImageView

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }  
    }
```

Required to add in Manifest File

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
```

I am Not Much aware sending that image MMS

For More Reference

[How to send image via MMS in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android)

Comment: I want the meaning of CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;