# Send mms in background service without showing any interface

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mms, android-mms

The below code is navigating me too default **`MMS`** app with the photo, text and number

```
Intent mmsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
mmsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "text");
mmsIntent.putExtra("address", "121");
mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo.jpeg")));
mmsIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
mmsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(mmsIntent);
```

What I need is to send mms in background without showing any kind of interface. I can send text sms using SmsManager using

```
SmsManagaer smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(num, null, "Help Me", null, null);
```

Can I use **[`smsManager.sendMultimediaMessage()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendMultimediaMessage(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.PendingIntent))** to send mms(*I'd tried this method and no success yet*)? If not then what it's use? And is there any other way to send mms in background?

Comment: Have you read the docs you link to? --> "Send an MMS message" what exactly is your question

Comment: @TimCastelijns : I need to send an mms via service (background)

Comment: That's not a question, be more clear please

Comment: @TimCastelijns : the first method it will navigate to the mms app... to send mms... that user need to click on send button after that.... But I want to send without any user interaction..... Everything should be done in background....

Comment: Have you tried smsManager.sendMultimediaMessage() yet?

Comment: @TimCastelijns : yes... and it's not worked at all...

Comment: Well why didn't you say so

Comment: I'd tried that after few days later not at the time when I posted this.......

Comment: You edited it today, could have edited that as well ;-)

Comment: @TimCastelijns : I just added the documentation.... :)

Comment: Yes but you left a question to which you already know the answer

Comment: @TimCastelijns :  yup I just updated , what is the use of the method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114684/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-tim-castelijns).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is creating [Implicit Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Types) which will launch another application depending upon the action you are sending. It may show Chooser dialog if there are more than one applications installed with the action registered in the intent filter.

To send a MMS without user interaction you can use `smsManager.sendMultimediaMessage()` to send MMS but this method was introduced since API version 21. You can refer the demo over [here](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/MmsMessagingDemo.java) to see how to send MMS using `sendMultimediaMessage()`.

To support versions prior to that you can integrate the solution listed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973016/1957455).

Comment: Thanks I will check it :)