# How to capture and send pictures via messaging

Tags: android

I want to capture image from front camera of android device and send via messaging automatically.How can I implement with android code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1**.First you need to create your `camera preview` with `Intent`(it opens your default camera app) or `Camera/Camera2 API`(for custom camera). Read the documentation from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) and apply code examples(even if you dont understand all the things, you will get them over the time your are working at app).

**2**.Then you need to attach your `file` to `MMS`. You cand find a lot of examples but take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android).

Hope it helps!