# Sending big SMS create multiples SMS in the outbox

Tags: android

I searched a solution to handle the sending of big SMS on Android. The solution appears to be to use the following method:

```
ArrayList<String> parts =smsManager.divideMessage(sms_content);    
smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(recipient.contact_phone, null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents);
```

If the received SMS message is correctly formated (only one big message), in my outbox I get multiple messages. Anyone has the clue of this?

Comment: Does parts represents an ArrayList?

Comment: have you tried sending an MMS instead? Typically they have a much larger limit (1000 on verizon)  than SMS (160), http://stackoverflow.com/q/2972845/794088

Comment: @ridoy yes it's an ArrayList<String> (I've updated my question)

Comment: @petey yes MMS might be a solution thanks, but I would have prefered to stick to SMS

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for the method divideMessage, it explicitly says that it will divide the message into multiple parts, none bigger than the maximum message size.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#divideMessage(java.lang.String)

Maximum SMS length is 160 characters.  MMS (Multimedia Messaging Service) would be a better option if you want an unbroken text message.  Checkout the SMSManager documentation, and the sendMultimediaMessage method in particular.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

Comment: Yes true there is a limit of 160 characters (140 in some cases if I understood well depending on languages). The fact that the message is divided is not an issue but I would like it no "visible" from users. When I send a big SMS from the Android SMS client, I do not see my message divided in my outbox and the receipient only sees one big message

Comment: Some messaging apps default to converting large SMS to MMS automatically, while other messaging apps default to dividing large SMS into separate SMS messages.  Depends on the choice of the developer.